# Possible aproach for MySQL replication

Tags: mysql, linux

This might be a duplicate questions asked before. But I need to understand a possible approach for my `ENV` running `innodb` engine.
Is it possible to upgrade a Master MySQL Server to `5.5` to `5.6` and  replication Slave which is on Version `5.7`

If this is possible then how do we perform this activity, because we am getting this below error of `Server_UUID` when replicating the Slave (Slave version 5.7.11 and Master Version 5.6.29)

```
Errno: 1593
Fatal error: The slave I/O thread stops because master and slave
have equal MySQL server UUIDs; these UUIDs must be different for
replication to work.
```

**Purpose is to `UPGRADE` both the server on the same version `5.7`**

Currently Version

**Server1 and Server2** are on `5.6.29`

Beginner in MySQL unable to understand the concept of replication with the new version, open for better suggestion.

Comment: Hmmm... Seems like you could somehow delete the UUID on one machine and let it recreate it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this article by the folks at Percona regarding duplicate UUIDs, it may be worth checking how the slave was created originally and checking out the `auto.cnf` settings on each server.
https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/21/beware-mysql-5-6-server-uuid-cloning-slaves/

Comment: I already have a setup of Master Slave Replication, I will be upgrading the Slave directly to 5.7, So there is not point in Cloning or duplicate UUIDs. Current ENV is working absolutely fine. At the time of `error 1593`  the UUID's were different.

Comment: I went through this link and checked all the differences, please have a look at it. http://datacharmer.blogspot.in/2015/08/changed-defaults-between-mysql-56-and-57.html